# Is it possible .FLV to .MP4 conversion on client side by ffmpeg-asm.js?

Tags: javascript, ffmpeg, mp4, flv, asm.js

Is it possible to do .FLV to .MP4 conversion on client side by ffmpeg-asm.js? 
The main issue lot's of mobile video players didn't support flash, but .FLV still popular at the internet ;(

Have no idea how to avoid server-side conversion and storing...

Comment: just being `flv` doesn't mean it's not `mp4`. for example, you can usually rename a downloaded flv video to `.mp4` and it will suddenly play in OS-provided media players. in short, you might be able to get it working in a <video> tag simply by changing the name/mime without touching the video bytes.

Comment: The above comment is VERY incorrect. mp4 and flv are not even in the same family of container.  If a rename works, then the player is ignoring the extension and deducing the correct format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to convert in browser to an MSE compatible format. But I would still recommend a server side conversion. Its is extreme cheap to switch containers from flv to mp4.

Comment: I'm trying to find way do it on fly without server side storing new .mp4 result :(

Comment: You are looking for mp4box